# How could I init a Fabric component with my customized init method, such as initWithDelegate:

Tags: react-native

The official document only described to init a RCTViewComponentView with initWithFrame，�and how could I init this view by other initialize methods?

Creating a Fabric component with initWithDelegate:  or   initWithDictionary:  etc